# What is the @ operator/delimiter in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, delimiter

While reading through the Python 3 Lexical analysis, I became slightly confused by the last section on operators[1] and delimiters. The `@` character is listed as both an operator and a delimiter, and `@=` is also listed as an augmented assignment operator. Following the form of other augmented assignment operators, I would expect this to mean that the `@` character can be used like so:

```
x = x @ y
```

or

```
x @= y
```

I have tried using it in this way with integers and strings without any success. I am familiar with using `@` for decorators, but fail to see how an augmented assignment operator is compatible with decorators.

What is the purpose of `@` and `@=` when used as an operator and/or delimiter in Python 3?

---

[1] Python 3 - Operators: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators

Comment: as an operator it's a matrix multiply. `a = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2); b = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2); print(a @ b)` shows `array([[ 2,  3], [ 6, 11]])`. I've only seen it work with numpy arrays though.

Comment: @Elliot you do appear to be correct, but I'd love to know if this works outside of numpy. Using your example, I tried `a @= b` and received the following error:

`TypeError: In-place matrix multiplication is not (yet) supported. Use 'a = a @ b' instead of 'a @= b'.`

Answer (score 1):

[Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) states

> The @ (at) operator is intended to be used for matrix multiplication. No builtin Python types implement this operator.

So you have to use numpy or other math libraries to make `x = x @ y` work.